# How do I create a list of worksheet names from a separate workbook and create a list using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create a list that will change depending on what file I'm working on so I can use it to create an index in another sheet.

Here's what I'm using to fill the column with sheet names, but I don't know how to convert it to a list called "SheetList".
My experience with VBA is what I've learned trying to modify what I've been able to find on StackOverflow.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
   
Dim myValue As Variant
Dim y As Workbook
Dim x As Workbook

myValue = InputBox("Enter File Name to OPEN IDM Quicksheet e.g. 123.xlsm")

Set y = Application.ActiveWorkbook
Set x = Workbooks(myValue)
    
For i = 2 To x.Sheets.Count
    y.ActiveSheet.Range("A" & i).Value = x.Sheets(i).Name
Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey I'm assuming `SheetList` should be in y, then:

```
' Create "SheetList" sheet in the end of workbook y
y.Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Name = "SheetList"
Dim ys As Worksheet
Set ys = y.Sheets(y.Sheets.Count)

' The worksheet names in x will be listed, starting from 2nd row
For i = 2 To x.Sheets.Count + 1
    ys.Range("A" & i).Value = x.Sheets(i - 1).Name
Next i
```